# MouseListener on multiple JLabels not working as intended

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I have 5 `JLabels` inside a `JPanel` which is inside a `JFrame`. I am adding the `JLabels` using a for loop which iterates through an array of Colors:

```
private JLabel target;

// This is the origin of the first label added.
Point origin = new Point(10, 20);

// This is the offset for computing the origin for the next label.
int offset = 200;

for (int i = 0; i &lt; layerColors.length; i++) {
    target = createColoredLabel(layerColors[i], origin, targetIcon);
    layeredPane.add(target, new Integer(i));
    origin.x += offset;
}

// Create and set up a colored label with icon image.
private JLabel createColoredLabel(Color color, Point origin, ImageIcon icon) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
    label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setBackground(color);
    label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    label.setBounds(origin.x, origin.y, 175, 263);
    label.addMouseListener(this);

    return label;
}
```

This creates 5 `JLabels`, with the same `ImageIcon` assigned to each, spread horizontally across the `JPanel`. Each one has a `MouseListener` added to it but only the last label to be added triggers the event.

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(target)) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```

I have a secondary issue involving a label containing an `ImageIcon` trailing my cursor which stops when I mouse over any of the 5 labels. I imagine it's a layer indexing issue but can't solve it.

Any help with these is much appreciated thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your mouse listener only beeps when the last label is clicked, since that's what you set target to. The code is far from SSCCE, btw.

Comment: Apologies for the poor quality code - am just starting out in software development. I see the flaw in my logic now, thanks. Any ideas as to how I can reference it so that any label will beep when clicked?

Comment: Get rid of the `e.getSource().equals(target)` part, or store an array of JLabels and loop through them all checking to see if they're the target.

Comment: Changed my event method to iterate through an array of JLabels as your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)` method only checks to see if the event source was a single component (target) which, as Geoffrey points out, is that last label you added. Try adding this as the first line in your `mouseClicked` method.

```
System.out.println("Color: " + ((JLabel)evt.getSource()).getBackground());
```

Note: Untested. Hopefully Color has a nice toString() implementation.
Note 2: You may get a `ClassCastException` if you added the class as a mouse listener to any other component.